# SQL: Display all the records related to common id

Tags: mysql

I have this following table

```
    id |         title
-------+--------------------
    16 | Little Women
    16 | The Tell-Tale Heart
    16 | Practical PostgreSQL
    16 | Dynamic Anatomy
    18 | The Cat in the Hat
    18 | Dune
    20 | A Space Odyssey
    20 | Goodnight Moon
    41 | The Shining
    41 | Programming Python
    41 | Perl Cookbook
```

I want the output should come like this shown below:

```
    id |         title
-------+------------------
    16 | Little Women
       | The Tell-Tale Heart
       | Practical PostgreSQL
       | Dynamic Anatomy
    18 | The Cat in the Hat
       | Dune
    20 | A Space Odyssey
       | Goodnight Moon
    41 | The Shining
       | Programming Python
       | Perl Cookbook
```

Displaying all records that is related with id in the right column using mysql. How can I do this? Please provide me the solution for this I will be very grateful.

Comment: you cant do this kind of display on mysql, thats the job of application script.

Comment: You better do this in your logic. SQL is not designed for that.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, juergen : We can't use union joins? Actually I have seen this but I don't know the solution so I was asking

Comment: @AmukSaxena Just because you have seen this done, doesn't mean it should be done. SQL is a language for data, not for prettifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(title separator '\n') FROM mytable GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Donot post exactly the same answer after 3 minutes

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @sadikhasan i haven't down voted but this approach will give results in different format as compare to the expected output of OP

Comment: I have already checked that they give same output as expected output

Comment: @gvee why it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Sadikhasan after your edit for the newline character, it *does* provide a reasonable answer. However I would strongly advise against this method as you are mixing presentation with data. Not a good idea in my book and not very portable! IF it works for the OP then fine, but I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: @Sadikhasan "...you  are mixing presentation with data."

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in your presentation layer e.g. your form, report, webpage, etc.

```
SELECT id
     , title
FROM   your_table
ORDER
    BY id
     , title
```

Your presentation code can then decide whether to display the ID each time.

Answer (score -1):

try this, you will get the results with comma separated.

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(title) FROM mytable GROUP BY id
```