# displaying related records vb.net mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, self-join, find-in-set

i have some strange searching criteria. first let me clarify it,

i have a table like this

```
     acct_no |   name  | connected_acct
  ----------------------------------
  1          |  name_1 | 5,6,7
  2          |  name_1 | 11,12,13
   ---------------------------------
```

1) here person "name_1" is the holder of all the account of "5,6,7"

what i want is, if i search for "acct_no" 1, then all the details of other connected accounts should also be displayed in a grind or whatever.

Thanks

--EDIT--
(1) i fount this question but i don't this it can solve my problem
[SQL: Display all the records related to common id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908684/sql-display-all-the-records-related-to-common-id)

(2) i forgot to mention that the database will store some of the fields in UTF format (some local language !)

Comment: Is normalizing your database an option?

Comment: yes, any solution can be implemented. actually it a half-completed project and i need to redesign it. so i can changes if necessary. :)

Comment: Then I strongly recomnend to normalize your tables. You could have an n-to-m connecting table for `[acct_no, connected_acct]` - that will make your life sooo much easier in the future.

Comment: thanks, Mureinik , i am also thinking for a new table for connected accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** function:

Try this:

```
SELECT b.acct_no, b.name 
FROM accounts a 
INNER JOIN accounts b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.acct_no, a.connected_acct) 
WHERE a.acct_no = 1;
```

Comment: thanks Saransh, i am trying both the tips from you and mureinik . 

i think i can now solve it. whenever i completed it i will post the sample code and the detailed solution. :)